# How can I see displayed data without having to refresh my page? (Fetch Post Request)

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

My fetch post request is successfully posting data to the database (I'm using PostGresSQL, ElephantSQL to be specific), however the new data only displays once I refresh the page.  How can I have it immediately rendered to the page?  Also, in my res => res.json(), I am also getting an error: Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.  I have no idea why this is and when I console log the "res" before I turn it to the json, I get a type of "basic".  Below is the code for my post function.

```
    const postMessage = () => {

  let password;
  const getInputValue = () => {
    password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  };
  
  let message;
  const getMessageValue = () => {
    message = document.getElementById('desc').value;
  };

  getInputValue();
  getMessageValue();

  //declare a object variable that has all properties you want to send (password, message, time)
  const obj = {
    password: password,
    message: message,
    created_at: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
  };

  fetch('/messages', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      // const list = addMessage.getElementsByTagName('li');
      // console.log(list)
      // list.innerText = `${message}`;
    
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error: ', error));

  getMessage(messageDisplay);  
};

addMessage.addEventListener('click', postMessage);
```

This is what I see when I console.log(res) before stringifying it.
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the console.log(res) before you stringify it

Comment: Sure, it should be on my post now.

Comment: Can u share the error screenshot?

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly the problem could be . It would be very nice if you can provide the fetch response as it is somewhere ( here or pastebin link)